# AllAuth Installation

Tags: django, facebook, twitter, django-allauth

I'm attempting to install and configure Django AllAuth and I've run into a plethora of obstacles. I'm afraid I'm simply missing a few basic concepts which might clear some things up.

1. In order to get basic social authentication working what setup needs to be done inside the social provider (Facebook, Twitter, etc.)
2. If this is the case then how would one develop locally because at first glance of Twitter's API setup it asks for redirect URLs which would get hairy considering everything right now is hosted locally.
3. When I try and go to `/accounts/login/` it redirects to `/accounts/profile/` every time. Can't seem to figure out what's causing this redirect.
4. I was previously using Userena for my user authentication and was going to add Django-social-auth but when I got into it that was giving me difficulty. I then found AllAuth which seemed to fit my needs perfectly but again, having some issues. Can anyone weigh in on this decision, would you recommend one over the other and if so why?

Facebook Error:
"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

When I click okay it redirects back to my site. My browser gives me a security error and when I proceed through that I end up back at my site displaying:
"Social Network Login Failure
An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Have a look here: https://speakerdeck.com/tedtieken/signing-up-and-signing-in-users-in-django-with-django-allauth

(specifically, slide 61 and above)

2) Simply use 127.0.0.1:8000 in your redirect URLs

3) By default allauth redirects to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, which is set out of the box to /accounts/profile/: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

4) As I am the author of allauth I will skip answering this question myself. Browse through the complete presentation referred to by 1) -- the initial slides provide a good comparison of the various options.

Comment: Thanks for your help that cleared a lot up. One thing I'm still stuck on though is the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Does that not redirect you after login? I haven't even gotten that far, any URL I try to navigate to under `/accounts/` redirects to `/accounts/profile/`. I tried changing the setting to `/accounts/login/` which caused my browser to give me an error that the "Page is not Redirecting Properly".

Comment: I'm actually having difficulty finding any documentation on the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` attribute. Its not listed in the configurable settings in the documentation. I found it in `app_settings.py` but it seems to indicate the default redirect should be to the site's root. Is this incorrect?

Comment: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is a Django setting, not an allauth one. Therefore, you won't find it in `app_settings.py` (I think you are mistaking with `ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`). If you visit the /accounts/login/ url while you are already logged in you are immediately redirected to the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, I've got most of it working now. Should I be able to login in through Facebook locally? Right now I'm getting an error on Facebook's site. I've updated my original question with this error.

Comment: The presentation was most useful to understand the state of the game in Django user/auth world - thank you. 
Any pointers to a easy to add "profile" community module that would add standard address/location fields (city, state , zip , country etc ) ? djangopackages comes up dry on that front