# django-allauth returns error Reverse for 'account_confirm_email' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using django-allauth along with django rest-auth.

here is the stacktrace:

```
[2016-02-15 23:45:35,093] ERROR [base:handle_uncaught_exception:256 8977] Internal Server Error: /api/rest-auth/registration/
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)     
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)                                           
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)                              
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 452, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)                                       
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)                                
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 44, in post
    self.form_valid(self.form)                                                  
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 36, in form_valid
    self.get_success_url())                                                     
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 157, in complete_signup
    signal_kwargs=signal_kwargs)                                                
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 114, in perform_login
    send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup)                       
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 286, in send_email_confirmation
    signup=signup)                                                              
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py", line 60, in send_confirmation
    confirmation.send(request, signup=signup)                                   
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/.ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py", line 121, in send
    activate_url = reverse("account_confirm_email", args=[self.key])            
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 578, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/.../webapps/project_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 495, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))                     
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_confirm_email' with arguments '(u'vgro7mdagterfbnqxlkihpnzs2bsp1iktwxng9vecznpeg8hcdv1eidco11tee3u',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

My urls for allauth

within my app "api":

api/urls.py

```
...
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$',confirm_email, name='confirm_email'),
url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
...
```

this is within an app named "api" within my project.

Using a shell I see:

```
python manage.py shell
Inside api.apps.ApiConfig.ready
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> 
>>> reverse('account_confirm_email', args=['l8ig7wqo1l4ypd7uosuoxlgnv2qxf5voe5ehwcd7s46hbprzyx9qwjgeontw5un6'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/divkis01/webapps/instaguide_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 578, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/divkis01/webapps/instaguide_test/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 495, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_confirm_email' with arguments '('l8ig7wqo1l4ypd7uosuoxlgnv2qxf5voe5ehwcd7s46hbprzyx9qwjgeontw5un6',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>>>
```

**while if I use api:account_confirm_email, it does return correct url.**

```
>>> reverse('api:account_confirm_email', args=['l8ig7wqo1l4ypd7uosuoxlgnv2qxf5voe5ehwcd7s46hbprzyx9qwjgeontw5un6'])
u'/api/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/l8ig7wqo1l4ypd7uosuoxlgnv2qxf5voe5ehwcd7s46hbprzyx9qwjgeontw5un6/'
```

Also as per [rest-auth FAQs](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html), the account-confirm-email should be overridden in your views, which is why I override the url:

```
url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(),
    name='account_confirm_email'),
```

with my url:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$',       confirm_email, name='confirm_email'),
```

There is another similar question here: [django-allauth returns error "Reverse ... with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126645/django-allauth-returns-error-reverse-with-arguments-and-keyword-argume)

but that problem is because of namespacing, while in my urls.py I do not namespace the allauth urls.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Was the answer below helpful? I'm hitting this same error in the same situation. The URL you added seems to be what's expected, also mentioned in this github issue: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/104, but when I override it in the same way I hit this error as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i decide this easy way, using RedirectView.as_view(), just write on you urls.py

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
url(r'^verifyemail/(?P<key>\w+)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/', permanent=True), name='account_confirm_email')
```

This redirect on main page, and send POST from Angular service to rest "rest_register" pattern.