# Django REST auth: error rendering django-allauth template after email confirmation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm using a Django REST Framework API to communicate from my AngularJS frontend to the Django backend, which is working really well. I installed the super helpful django-rest-auth package as well as their optional registration add on. Authentication works, and registration mostly works as well.

My problem is that the confirmation link in the confirmation email sent to the new user gives me a NoReverseMatch error. Thanks to the django-rest-auth [FAQ](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html), I know the confirmation doesn't work by default and requires overriding but I mirrored what the poster of [this](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/104) question did. My urls:

```
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email as allauthemailconfirmation
...
url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', allauthemailconfirmation, name="account_confirm_email"),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
...
```

And the exact error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/ahhuvpetqmcsd6hjlgrjuru11mwfkpk9sljmfbuprxwz8elnajabr84vusnmdw7r/
Reverse for 'account_email' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

The poster of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418428/django-allauth-returns-error-reverse-for-account-confirm-email-with-arguments) question seems to have had the same issue, though I don't understand how the one answer applies, and it's not accepted, so I'm not sure if it even works.

**EDIT**:

Based on the first comment below, I tried changing the URL name to `account_email`. This still resulted in an error, but after re-reading the error, I realized it's thrown during render of a default `django-allauth` template, after the allauth view has handled the confirmation:

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\allauth\templates\base.html, error at line 26
Reverse for 'account_email' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
    16      <li>{{message}}</li>
17      {% endfor %}
18        </ul>
19      </div>
20      {% endif %}
21  
22      <div>
23        <strong>Menu:</strong>
24        <ul>
25      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
26  
        <li><a href="
      {% url 'account_email' %}
      ">Change E-mail</a></li>


27      <li><a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Sign Out</a></li>
28      {% else %}
29      <li><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Sign In</a></li>
30      <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
31      {% endif %}
32        </ul>
33      </div>
34      {% block content %}
35      {% endblock %}
36      {% endblock %}
```

So I think the code I used from the linked github issue is correct for the confirmation email, and this error happens during render of the template after the allauth view confirms the email address. I would expect the URLs in lines 26-30 above to be part of the `include('rest_auth.registration.urls')` set, since the django-rest-auth registration option uses django-allauth.

I'm not sure what I'd need to do to get this URL working if the allauth view is handling the confirmation correctly. I could be wrong about that guess, though.

**EDIT 2**
I took the advice from a comment below and printed off all the URLs:

```
>>> show_urls(urls.urlpatterns)
^api/
   ^$
   ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$

   ....autogenerated viewset URLs....

 ^api-browse/
   ^login/$
   ^logout/$
 ^rest-auth/
   ^password/reset/$
   ^password/reset/confirm/$
   ^login/$
   ^logout/$
   ^user/$
   ^password/change/$
 ^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$
 ^rest-auth/registration/
   ^$
   ^verify-email/$
   ^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$
 ^$

 ....explicitly added URLs for custom viewset methods...

 ^register/$
 ^login/$
 ^logout$
 ^admin/

   ....admin URLs....
```

The `NoReverseMatch` error makes sense now, since the URL patterns on the allauth confirm email view simply aren't present.

I noticed in the linked StackOverflow question that the poster had included the allauth urls as so:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

When I added this line, it worked!

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? In eror it says: Reverse for 'account_email' and you have this in url name="account_confirm_email", can you try with the same name in url?

Comment: Thanks for the idea- I think it should be `account_confirm_email` and that this NoReverseMatch comes from a URL on a basic django-allauth template that has no reverse. I added some details to the original post outlining all this

Comment: I don't understand why you get the error, but I can give other idea to debug this, check url patterns via show_urls command. This command is available if you install [django-extenstions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io)

Comment: Thanks for the idea- I'll try that as soon as I get home! I'm wondering if this issue is related to the fact that users with a non-verified email can login, which doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recap the final edit above, the issue here was that I was attempting to use the `django-allauth` default email confirmation template, but hadn't included the `allauth` urls explicitly.

I didn't think that step was required since `django-rest-framework`'s registration option uses `allauth`, but since the `account_confirm_email` view must be overridden anyway, the authors of that package seem to expect users to POST the key to `/verify_email/`.

To make use of the `allauth` email confirmation template, include the following in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Comment: I think that I love you. I was about to wreak havoc.

Comment: Glad it helped! I've found that not many of my django-rest-auth questions get answered, so I try to post answers if I ever figure them out.

Comment: Just to clarify. Notice that `allauth` must be included **after** `rest-auth` URLS in order to properly override `rest-auth`

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the reputation to comment. After searching several posts on github and stackoverflow, found the answer by dkhaupt to work perfectly.

I will add a few points to others who are also struggling with email verification in `django-rest-auth` or `dj-rest-auth`. I used a combination of this blog https://www.rootstrap.com/blog/registration-and-authentication-in-django-apps-with-dj-rest-auth/ and above post by @dkhaupt to make it work.

I was ***NOT*** able to make it work from the pointers in other popular forums where this issue has been discussed for 5 years (unless I missed some other link to the solution).

- https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/290
- https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/292